# google-api-php-client download zip from Git has only one directory src/Google

Tags: git, github, google-api-php-client

Git : [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)

I only see

```
src/Google
```

how do I download the other directory ?

```
/example

/style

/tests
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Git on your computer

Run

```
git clone https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client
```

You will have the whole directory structure.